# Smali syntax for DalvikVM opcodes

Tags: java, android, dalvik, smali

### Prologue

I am trying to learn about DalvikVM instructions using the Smali/Baksmali assembler/disassembler for dex files.

### Problem

From this java file

```
package gd;

class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      System.out.println("Hello!");
    }
}
```

I have generated the following smali assembly file:

```
.class Lgd/Hello;
.super Ljava/lang/Object;
.source "Hello.java"


# direct methods
.method constructor <init>()V
    .registers 1

    .prologue
    .line 3
    invoke-direct {p0}, Ljava/lang/Object;-><init>()V

    return-void
.end method

.method public static main([Ljava/lang/String;)V
    .registers 3
    .parameter

    .prologue
    .line 6
    sget-object v0, Ljava/lang/System;->out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;

    const-string v1, "Hello!"

    invoke-virtual {v0, v1}, Ljava/io/PrintStream;->println(Ljava/lang/String;)V

    .line 7
    return-void
.end method
```

My question is about the following line.

```
sget-object v0, Ljava/lang/System;->out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
```

As I understand this loads the static object `PrintStream` of the `java.lang.System` class into the `v0` register. Now, what does this `out:` mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PrintStream is actually the type of the thing being loaded. The object you're loading might be referred to as `java.lang.System.out`, where `java.lang` is the package, `System` is the class, and `out` is the member (a static field) to be loaded.

You can see the same pattern in the invoke-virtual: `java.io` is the package, `PrintStream` is the class and `println` is the member (in this case, an instance method). In both cases, the member is preceded with a `->`. I don't know if this pattern is consistent throughout Smali.

I found http://source.android.com/tech/dalvik/dalvik-bytecode.html invaluable when I was playing with dalvik stuff, although in this case its contribution was just identifying that sget-object only took two arguments. That told me the `->out:` business had to be part of the static field reference.

Comment: Updated URL for anyone landing on this question/answer: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/dalvik-bytecode

Answer (score 1):

Actually it reads the static field named `out` of the class `java.Lang.System. The (expected) type of that field is`java.io.PrintStream`.