# What does ".line" mean in smali code syntax? (Android-Smali Code)

Tags: java, android, mobile, syntax, smali

[Please take a look at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11671545/smali-syntax-for-dalvikvm-opcodes?rq=1)

Decompiled smali code contains things like `.line 3`  or `.line 7`.

I cannot understand what `.line` is supposed to be, please elaborate on the usage.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`.line n` markers are used for debugging and stacktraces. When an exception goes uncaught, or the stacktrace needs to be filled in, the line number is taken from the `.line` statement. If this were missing, then stacktraces would lack line numbers.

Comment: can i remove .line markers when i want to recompile smali codes ?

Comment: @user2525702 As per what I have already stated, yes, but debugging will be harder.

Comment: @user2525702 `.line` is the line in the original Java sourcecode that translates to the following part of smali. If you remove them you probably don't get nice Exception stacktraces  like `at com.foo.bar.Bar(Bar.java:85)`

Comment: @user2525702 But *why* do you want to do this?  Simply recompile the original source with the modifications.

Comment: @Simon its useful when you don't have the original source

Comment: @DevZer0  Like when?  In what scenario do you not have the code?  Either; a) it's your code, b) it's open source, c) the developer has provided the code.  There are no other legitimate scenarios - or are there?

Comment: @Simon its useful when you inspect closed source application for potential malware code in them.

Comment: Thanks @Andrey. You Just Saved me Hours of Bullsh*t

Answer (score 1):

Almost everything in the smali language has a direct analogue in the dalvik bytecode or dex format.

The .line directive in particular corresponds to the position entries emitted by the state machine that the debug_info_item defines, as specified at https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/dex-format.